# RenderToHtml viewfile and return a string?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I made a small MVC Framework, but i need that my view Class can return the page as string but before that apply all the variables. How can this be done?

```
class View{
    private $registry;
    private $vars = array();
    private $file;
    public function __set($index, $value){
        $this->vars[$index] = $value;
    }

    public function  __construct($controller, $action){
        $this->file = "Views/".$controller."/".$action.".php";
        $this->registry = new Registry();
    }

  public function renderToHtml(){
        try{
            if(file_exists($this->file)){

                foreach ($this->vars as $key => $value){
                   $$key = $value;
                }

                /** include $this->file; **/ 
//apply vars on file 
                return $html;
            }else{
                throw new Exception("No such View file");
            }
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            echo '<h1>Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "</h1>";
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function indexAction(){
   $html = new View('SomeController', 'htmlview');
   $html->somevar = "blabla";
   $this->View->fubar = $html->renderToHtml();
   $this->View->render() //this will render the current action/view (index) 
}
```

so the htmlview will be a partial in regular indexView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Example:

```
ob_start();
/* your error catch */
$render_html = ob_get_flush();
return $render_html;
```

Comment: Yes this will work but the include $this->file will still include the view file in the parent view, so it will be shown 2x

Comment: Pass in a paramter to `$html->renderToHtml($ob=true);' so can decide when to do ob_start() ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you nee to get the file contents and replace all the variables there.